# Set Country / Region field Access via Active Directory Delegation

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, group-policy, delegation

After creating a security group for special permissions (edit User Objects fields like Street, ZIP etc.) I have a problem of not being able to delegate permission for the field "Country/Region" on a forest functional level of Server 2008 R2.

What I've been doing so far:

- EDIT dssec.dat set co=0;

  => Country/Region is available in AD Delegation Wizard (success)
- RESET CUST DELEGATIONs and DELEGATE Read/Write Control on specific
  fields including Country / Region

=> All specific fields except for Country/Region been able to edit

- RESET CUST DELEGATIONs and DELEGATE Permission set "Read/Write public
  Information"

=> All specific fields except for Country/Region been able to edit

- RESET CUST DELEGATIONs and DELEGATE Permission set "Read/Write
  private Information"

=> Country/Region editable as well as fields like LogonName/Logon pre W2K

I would like to know how to delegate Permission on the Country/Region field without granting too much rights!

Comment: I've made also sure that I am connected on the correct Domain Controller as well as it shouldn't matter as the replication works fine

Comment: As I do not have the required rep yet I'd appreciate if someone set a small Bounty, as I have spent a lot of time again today resulting in either none or too much access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESET CUST DELEGATIONs and DELEGATE Permission set "Read/Write private Information"

=> Country/Region editable as well as fields like LogonName/Logon pre W2K

This step done the trick once making sure that the permissions are replicated correctly before continuing the tests